# Checkbox doesn't change its value on click in React todo application

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Please help me with this I don't understand exactly where I doing wrong. So when I click on the checkbox values are not changing(if it's by default `true` when I click on the click it should the `false`). For that in `onChange` in `todoList` component I am calling `handleClick` function there I change the `todo.completed` value(basically toggling the values).

In `App.js` *inside the `handleClick` method* When do `console.log(todo)` before returning from the map function value is toggling fine, but it is not updated in the `updatedTodo`.

App.js

```
import TodosData from "./todoData";
import TodoList from "./todoList";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: TodosData
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange(id) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const updatedTodo = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
        // console.log(updatedTodo);
        if(todo.id === id) {
          console.log("before the opt "+todo.completed);
          todo.completed = !todo.completed
          console.log("after the opt "+todo.completed);
        }
        //console.log(todo);
        return todo;
      })
      console.log(updatedTodo);
      return {
        todos: updatedTodo
      }
    });
  }

  render() {

    const todoDataComponents = this.state.todos.map(item => {
      return <TodoList key = {item.id} item = {item} handleChange = {this.handleChange} />
    })
    return (
      <div className="todo-list">{todoDataComponents}</div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

todoList.jsx

```
class TodoList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {}
    }
    render() {
        // console.log(this.props)
        return (
            <div className="todo-item">
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    checked={this.props.item.completed}
                    onChange = {() => this.props.handleChange(this.props.item.id)}
                />
                <p>{this.props.item.text}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default TodoList;
```

todoData.js

```
const TodosData = [
    { id: 1, text: "Coding", completed: true },
    { id: 2, text: "Exercise", completed: false },
    { id: 3, text: "Learning", completed: true },
    { id: 4, text: "Programming", completed: true },
    { id: 5, text: "inspire", completed: false },
    { id: 6, text: "motivation", completed: true }
];

export default TodosData;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see any error in your `handleChange()` method, it should work fine. However, I've just updated some of your code which you can test below.

I changed the name of your `TodoList` as it's not really a list but an item. I also changed it to a functional component as it's only presentational, there is no need to have its own state. Instead of adding a `p` tag after the `input`, you should use a `label` to make it accessible.

<s>I haven't really changed anything inside your `handleChange()` method, only removed the `console.log`s and it works as expected.</s>

**Update**: You're using `React.StrictMode`, where React renders everything twice on dev. As your `handleChange()` runs twice, it sets the clicked todo's `completed` state twice, making it to set back to its original state. So if it's `false` on first render it sets to `true` on click, but it's rendered again and on the second one it's back to `false`. You won't notice it as it's pretty fast.

To avoid it, you need to avoid mutating anything. So I've updated your `onChange` handler, it returns a new object if the `completed` property is changed.

Feel free to run the code snippet below and click on the checkboxes or the item texts.

```js
const TodosData = [
  { id: 1, text: 'Coding', completed: true },
  { id: 2, text: 'Exercise', completed: false },
  { id: 3, text: 'Learning', completed: true },
  { id: 4, text: 'Programming', completed: true },
  { id: 5, text: 'Inspire', completed: false },
  { id: 6, text: 'Motivation', completed: true },
];

function TodoItem(props) {
  const { handleChange, item } = props;

  return (
    <div className="todo-item">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id={`item-${item.id}`}
        checked={item.completed}
        onChange={() => handleChange(item.id)}
      />
      <label htmlFor={`item-${item.id}`}>{item.text}</label>
    </div>
  );
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: TodosData,
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(id) {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      const updatedTodo = prevState.todos.map((todo) => {
        return todo.id === id ? {
          ...todo,
          completed: !todo.completed,
        } : todo;
      });

      return {
        todos: updatedTodo,
      };
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { todos } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="todo-list">
        {todos.map((item) => (
          <TodoItem
            key={item.id}
            item={item}
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>, 
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an additional variable, you can do it in one line. Can u see if this works for you.

```
handleChange(id) {
    this.setState(prevState => prevState.map(todo => todo.id === id ? {...todo, completed: !todo.completed} : todo )
}
```

Comment: Hi, @Someone it is not working for me.
I tried with
` handleChange(id) {
    this.setState(prevState => prevState.todos.map(todo => todo.id === id ? {...todo, completed: !todo.completed} : todo ))
}`

you can check my code in [link] (https://codesandbox.io/s/recttodo-cmbqz?file=/src/App.js:314-617)